# How to get the key from value in key/value pair in redis store client?

Tags: node.js, dictionary, redis, socket.io, node-redis

I am storing username/SocketID pairs in redis store for my socket.io chat application.

When the user disconnects i need to remove the username/socketID pair from the redis store. I have seen how to get the value from a key but never a key from a value. Is it possible? or either way how can i delete the key/value pair from just the value. Here's my code

For adding to store on connect

```
socket.on('username', function (username) {

    client.set(username, socket.id, function (err) {
        console.log(username + ":" + socket.id);
    });

});
```

For disconnect, the client wont know when the disconnect will happen, might happen due to loss of internet connectivity but when the socket disconnects it always hits the "disconnect" event. In this event i need to delete the username/socketID pair.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {

// dont know the username??

    client.del(username, socket.id, function (err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            socket.disconnect();
            console.log(socket.id + " DISCONNECTED");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to store **two** pairs. One with `username/id` and one with `id/username`. So whatever information you have, you can get the other and as a result the other key/value pair too.

Comment: Thanks, i did go ahead with this solution. But i was hoping there would be a more straight forward solution to this issue.

Comment: If have have an index (key) and data (value). You cannot search for data without the index. Or you make a "table scan". That is the nature of index/data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you incorporate the socket.io Id into the key e.g.

```
id:username
```

Then you could do something like this

```
client.keys([socket.id + ':*'], function (err, result) {
    if (err){
        //handle in some way
    }

    for (var r in result) {
        var key = result[r];

        client.del(key, function(err, result){
            // handle in some way
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have to find the socketID from username as well. As in when i have too send a message to some other user, then i retrieve the socket.id given the username and send message to that socketID . So i definitely need a way to know the key from value and the other way as well.

Comment: In that case, see the answer above from heinob and store two keys. I'd recommend using colons over slashes to be more in keeping with expected Redis key formats though