# Get HashKey from value of a subkey in Redis

Tags: node.js, redis

i have a hash key-values (represented in JSON) like this

```
"sessionid1" : {
                   "username":"lakshman",
                   "fullName":"lakshman pilaka"
                 }

"sessionid2" : {
                   "username":"suresh",
                   "fullName":"suresh kumar"
                 }
"sessionid3" : {
                   "username":"suresh",
                   "fullName":"suresh kumar"
                 }
```

I am looking for a command in redis which takes `"username"`, `"suresh"` as inputs and returns `["sessionid2", "sessionid3"]`

possible ?

if the information is important, i am using `redis_node`

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215996/how-to-get-the-key-from-value-in-key-value-pair-in-redis-store-client) can help.

Comment: You need to build an index from `username` and `suresh` to `session id`